# multiplying two variables in DOM createElement

Tags: php, mysql, dom

1.I have this code:

```
$dom->createElement('InvoicesValue', $arrayValue));
```

and I must change $arrayValue on: $arrayValue*$arrayTax. Unfortunately, when I write text like this, I have error:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types
```

How I can repair this?

I paste only important piece of code:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){ 
    $arrayValue       =  $array[$i]['valueInvoice']; //variable imported from MySQL
    $arrayTax         =  ['0.23'];
    $fctrl = $dom->createElement('InvoiceCtrl');
    $root->appendChild($fctrl);
    $fctrl->appendChild($InvoicesValue = $dom->createElement('InvoicesValue', arrayValue*$arrayTax));
}
```

Do you have any idea? :)

Comment: You lost $ sing in `createElement('InvoicesValue', arrayValue*$arrayTax)`. Now php use string constant 'arrayValuew` instead variable  $arrayValue. Just add $

Comment: @Kacper I see you have added the second question on the end of the first. Can you make a new question for that? Otherwise it gets complicated for anyone answering the question. The way tickets are answered and accepted is based around a new "ticket" for each question.

Comment: I don't think you want `setAttributeNS` at all; rather just use `setAttribute`. `$root->setAttribute( 'version', $version); $root->setAttribute('systemCode', 'Text (1)');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You're trying to store a float as an array. The value `$arrayTax` should be a simple float value, not an array

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){ 
    $arrayValue       =  $array[$i]['valueInvoice']; //variable imported from MySQL

    $arrayTax         =  0.23;  //Change this line to a plain float literal, not an array literal

    $fctrl = $dom->createElement('InvoiceCtrl');
    $root->appendChild($fctrl);
    $fctrl->appendChild($InvoicesValue = $dom->createElement('InvoicesValue', arrayValue*$arrayTax));
}
```

Comment: It work, thanks! Maybe you have any idea for my question 2? I added few secounds ago.

Comment: @Kacper If it works, can you upmark and accept the answer please? I'll look at the other question.

Comment: @Kacper I see you have added the second question on the end of the first. Can you make a new question for that? Otherwise it gets complicated for anyone answering the question. The way tickets are answered and accepted is based around a new "ticket" for each question.

Comment: thanks for help, but question two i resolved alone. Take a accepted answer :)